# How to persist data using expressjs, reactjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have created a simple chat app. I want to persist data so whenever I refresh it should show the previous chat also. Currently, I am using socket.io, reactjs and nodejs/express. When I refresh the page all chats are gone why so?
I think my backend is not working in below code. Currently, only client side is working and not backend why so? What is wrong in server.js?

Code:

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const socket = require('socket.io');

const app = express();

server = app.listen(5000, function(){
  console.log('server is running on port 5000')
});

io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id);

  socket.on('SEND_MESSAGE', function(data){
      io.emit('RECEIVE_MESSAGE', data);
  })

});
```

chat.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './chat.css'
import Icon, {
    Ionicons,
} from 'react-web-vector-icons'
import io from "socket.io-client";

export default class Chat extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            message: '',
            messages: []
        };

        this.socket = io('localhost:5000');

        this.socket.on('RECEIVE_MESSAGE', function(data){
            addMessage(data);
        });

        const addMessage = data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({messages: [...this.state.messages, data]});
            console.log(this.state.messages);
        };

        this.sendMessage = ev => {
            ev.preventDefault();
            this.socket.emit('SEND_MESSAGE', {
                message: this.state.message
            })
            this.setState({message: ''});
        }

    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
                <div id="status"></div>
                <div id="chat">
                    <div className="card">
                        <div id="messages" className="card-block">
                            {this.state.messages.map(message => {
                                    return (
                                        <div className="msgCard">{message.message}</div>
                                    )
                            })}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="column">
                            <input id="inputmsg" type="text" placeholder="Enter Message...."
                            value={this.state.message} onChange={ev => this.setState({message: ev.target.value})}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="column2">
                            <button id="send" className="button" onClick={this.sendMessage}>Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Note: backend is working on port 5000 and client on 3000 using concurrently.
When I go to port `5000` I am getting error 404 why so?

Screenshot:

[image]

Chat app:

[image]

Comment: Hey, I have update my answer hv u checked it now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save somewhere you data. Yes it is possible without a database. Here I have implemented it using `LocalStorage` which resides in the browser.

```
this.state = {
        // Get previously saved messages.
        message: '',
        messages: JSON.parse(LocalStorage.getItem('messages')) || [],
    };


const addMessage = data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({messages: [...this.state.messages, data]});
        console.log(this.state.messages);
        // Saving to HTML5 LocalStorage
        LocalStorage.setItem('messages' , JSON.stringify(this.state.messages);
    };
```

I hope it helps. Leave a comment if u face any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your server code not storing chat data anywhere in any db. its now act like middleware receiving the message and sending message to client.

you are listening port 5000 but your not handling any incoming requests so its throwing error.

Comment: But is database necessary when using socket.io ? I am not using any database to store the chat.

Comment: Is it possible without database ?

Comment: its depends your requirement. We can achieve using local storage in client side. But if you want access access chat different client then we need to store in server side.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question first:

> Note: backend is working on port 5000 and client on 3000 using concurrently. When I go to port 5000 I am getting error 404 why so ?

Your node/express/socket-io backend is running on port 5000. Your dev-server for your react application (which serves HTML/JS/CSS files) is running on port 3000 (I'm assuming). Trying to connect to your node/express/socket-io backend with your browser (which tries to fetch files via HTTP protocol) results in a 404.

To persist older messages, as others have said, you need to use a db. either `localStorage`, which stores the data to PC, server side, you could use in memory storage (just `push` old message in an array, and replay when user connect), or actual db like mongo, sql, etc.

Comment: So basically I am getting error 404 because it is not connected to any database am I right ?

Comment: I have one more doubt -> even if I see the console on port 5000 I am not able to see anything there why so ? `server = app.listen(5000, function(){
  console.log('server is running on port 5000')
});` why does it not show `server is running on port 5000` when I go to port 5000

Comment: `app.listen(5000, function() { /* logging */ })` runs the backend that listens to `socket-io` specific messages (that is it is expecting messages from a `socket-io` client). when your browser pings `http://localhost:5000`, because the server is not configured to answer to a browser, that's why you get a 404 error. If you want to see something in the browser, you can add the following line between `const app = express()` and `app.listen`: `app.get('/', (req, res) => { res.status(200).send('OK') })`